# Angular Pipe Template Context

Tags: angular, templates, pipe

Is it possible to get the exact template location/context/wrapping html element where a pipe is used within a template (without having to pass the pipe any extra arguments)?

I tried injecting `ElementRef` into the pipe constructor but this returns the entire component element, not the exact DOM location.

Template Example:

```
...
<div>
    {{ 'blah' | myPipe}}
</div>
...
```

I'd like to get access to the pseudo element exactly where the pipe is evaluated or the wrapping `div`.

**Current Angular version 8**

Comment: Why? what's your end goal?

Comment: @yurzui From OP: (without having to pass the pipe any extra arguments). I was messing with that until I re-read OP

Comment: @KurtHamilton Thanks, I need to read carefully

Comment: If you're on Angular 9 then injecting ElementRef in your pipe will give your reference to the element where your pipe is used. In this case it will be TextNode

Comment: @yurzui perfect! Thanks for that.

Comment: @yurzui just tested... how are you getting that? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-o4pxyj?file=app%2Ftest.pipe.ts doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @Stevanicus Stackblitz doesn't support Ivy enabled yet, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular 9 Ivy the ElementRef injected in a Pipe points to the place where that Pipe is actually used.

**test.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'test',
})
export class TestPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.info("-->", this.el);
  }
...
```

**html**

```
<div class="bob">
  {{ 'mystring' | test }}
</div>
```

[image]

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/ocGt3hz5JcyxuzjL7vJm)**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @yurzui

Answer (score 0):

In general, Pipe is like function to facilitate manipulating input data before binding to target property. It is not intended for manipulating DOM. If you want to manipulate DOM, then do it in Component or define Directive for it.